# Which NFC/RFID cards are detected best by Nexus 7 2013

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, nexus-7

I am looking for the cards that are detected the best by the NFC module of the **2013 Nexus 7**. Does it detect RFID cards as well? Which cards have the best detection range, is it NFC or RFID? I am trying with a NTAG203 but it is only detected if placed at the back of the device and it takes a bit of time. I am hoping for something that works from the front.

I have been testing on the old 2012 Nexus 7 and it was able to detect cards (like the Mifare DESFire EV1 - which is not detected at all by the new Nexus 7) when placed on the front at the top. Hoping to find the right card that will allow me to do the same on the new version of the tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in the end I made a test with all the tag types I could get my hands on. I can't seem to get better results with any specific tag, they all seem to perform the same. That includes:

- MIFARE Ultralight
- MIFARE Ultralight C
- NTAG203
- MIFARE DESFire 4k
- Broadcom Topaz 512

And this one does not work at all:

- MIFARE Classic 1k

Comment: Besides 1k any MIFARE Classic (Mini, 4k) won't work due to the NFC chipset (Broadcom) used in the 2013 Nexus 7.

Comment: Right, my comment was specific to MIFARE Classic (which exists in the three variants 1K, 4K and Mini). MIFARE DESFire is a different product (which comes in the flavors 2K, 4K 8K and EV1 1K, EV1 4K, EV1 8K)

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying with a NTAG203 but it is only detected if placed at the back of the device and it takes a bit of time. I am hoping for something that works from the front.

That probably is only partially driven by the tag type and partially on other factors, such as the physical tag construction (e.g., sticker vs. card vs. other form factors, plastic vs. titanium vs. steel vs. other housing materials). I would not assume that all tags of type X will work on the front just because you get one tag of type X to work on the front.

That being said, you're welcome to try a Topaz 512.

Answer (score 1):

Aaarrggh didn't realise this. I am developing with Samsung s3 and mifare classic card 1k and needed a bigger interface. I guess i am stuck with a new Nexus 2013

Answer (score 0):

> [...] but it is only detected if placed at the back of the device [...] I am hoping for something that works from the front.

NFC tags can be read/written on the the backside of the mobile device only. On the one hand this is due to technical reasons: The antenna which emits the power to supply the tag is on the backside and has only a range of a few millimeters, it just can't communicate through the electronic circuitry of the phone/tablet itself. On the other hand this short range was chosen by design for security reasons.